# Jquery click function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

So i have `click` function and i'm calling this function couple times on same div, so basicly i have this kind of div:

```
<div id="upload_submit" class="upload_submit">Content</div>
```

and i have two `click` functions:

```
    //first function
    $('.upload_submit').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('upload_submit');
        $(this).addClass('upload_cancel');
    });
    //second one
    $(".upload_cancel").click(function(){
        alert('test')
    });
```

So by default my div have class `upload_submit` after i click on that div i change class to `upload_cancel` so now if i click again i should get alert but for some reason it doesn't happen, what could be wrong?

Comment: you haven't delegated the events properly, and event binding only happens when the selector matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.bind()` (which .click is a wrapper around) only binds to elements existing at the time of the call. But you are dynamically changing the class meaning that there is no `.upload_cancel` to bind to when you try to bind it. Therefore you need a [`delegated event`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
//first function
$(document).delegate('.upload_submit', 'click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('upload_submit');
    $(this).addClass('upload_cancel');
});
//second one
$(document).delegate('.upload_cancel', 'click', function(){
    alert('test')
});
```

Or if you are using 1.7+ you can use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) syntax:

```
//first function
$(document).on('click', '.upload_submit', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('upload_submit');
    $(this).addClass('upload_cancel');
});
//second one
$(document).on('click', '.upload_cancel', function(){
    alert('test')
});
```

What this will do instead is bind a handler to the `document` element for a click event. It will then check if the triggering element matches your selector you passed in, if it does it will call your handler. This means that you can add and remove elements matching the selector provided and it will still call your click event handler correctly since the event is bound to the `document` not your specific element.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEgt5/1/) example of this solution.

For more information you can start reading [this article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/).

Comment: `live` is discouraged. Use `on` if you're using jQuery 1.7.1, or `delegate` otherwise.

Comment: @fuzzyDunlop `live` is not just discouraged but it will be [deprecated](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/). `.delegate/.bind` are fine though and in my opinion have better api design than `.on`

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery .on() function which is documented here: 
http://api.jquery.com/on/

This is needed because the class doesn't exist on DOM ready, but it is added on runtime.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The second event listener registration (`$(".upload_cancel").click()`) will only apply to elements that match the selector `.upload_cancel` at the time you call `click()`.  So if your `div` doesn't have that class until after it's clicked, that event listener won't be registered to it.  You can look into jQuery.live().

Answer (score 1):

If you are using atleast v1.7, you can achieve the same out as `.live` using `.on`

`$(document).on("click", ".upload_cancel", function(event){`

This was added in v1.7 and has the same functionality as the `.live` and as such `.live` was depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The example using `live` depends on deprecated code in the latest version of jQuery (1.7.1). You should use this instead:

```
$('.upload-submit').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('upload-submit');
    $(this).addClass('upload-cancel');
});

$('.upload-cancel').on('click', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

If you have a version older than that, use `delegate`:

```
$(document).delegate('.upload-submit', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('upload-submit');
    $(this).addClass('upload-cancel');
});

$(document).delegate('.upload-cancel', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```